# e How to select records that are not associated with a parent model - Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

First, my models:

```
User has_many :subscriptions
     has_many :courses, :through => :subscriptions

Subscription belongs_to :both

Course has_many :subscriptions
       has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
```

To get the User's courses that are subscribed is easy enough:

```
@subscribed_courses = current_user.courses
```

**Now I want to get a list of 5 random courses that the current_user is not associated with** (for a "You might also like..." function on the user's homepage). What's the best way to do this? Would it be performant to select all Courses and then, in ruby, limit the hash to just the courses not in the `@subscribed_courses` instance variable? How would I do that if it's the best way?

#### Edit:

For example, `Course.joins(:subscription)` will give me all courses associated with a subscription. I want to query for courses that the user is not subscribed to, including those courses that no one has subscribed to yet (and so, aren't associated with a subscription). Sorry I didn't make that clearer before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Course.joins(:subscriptions).where('subscriptions.user_id <> ?', current_user.id).order('random()').limit(5)
```

Comment: Use [`random_record`](http://rahult.github.com/random_record/) gem instead of the built-in `random()`, it's not quite reliable in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks Mik_Die and Ryan. Please see my edit since I clarified my question a bit. This is still helpful since I didn't know how to query for random records, but this will only return courses that someone (not the current_user) has subscribed to. It doesn't include courses that have no subscription associated. Sorry for being nit-picky, but that's the part I'm really having trouble figuring out.

Comment: You can use outer join instead ```Course.joins('left outer join subscriptions on subscriptions.course_id = courses.id').where('not subscriptions.user_id = ?', current_user.id)```